# Passando valores entre telas

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Gostaria de uma ajuda, sou novato no desenvolvimento android e estou tentando desenvolver um app. 
Basicamente vou precisar de 4 "telas" onde a 1 é digitado um valor, segue para a próxima, nesta "tela" escolhe uma opção e vai para a próxima, dependendo da opção selecionada, carrega opções, nesta 3 "tela", escolhe uma opção ou digita um valor e vai para a próxima "tela" e nesta 4 "tela" mostra um resultado pegando os valores escolhidos ou digitados nas telas anteriores.
Preciso o que devo fazer e quais os passos, classes, etc que preciso utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luciano, para enviar um dado para outro tela utilize o seguinte comando na chamada da tela seguinte:

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SegundaTela.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("parametro_1", 2);
                mIntent.putExtra("parametro_2", 500);
                startActivity(mIntent);
                finish();
```

Para receber o parâmetro na segunda tela, no evento onCreate, coloque o seguinte comando:

```
private int tipo;
private int valor;

tipo = getIntent().getIntExtra("parametro_1", 1);
valor = getIntent().getIntExtra("parametro_2", 10);
```

Lembrando, que o nome do parâmetro é case sensitve e as variáveis tipo e valor, usei como exemplo, você pode substituir pelas suas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma string estatica publica que recebe o valor e chamar na janela seguinte, é bem simples.

exemplo:

```
public class main{public static string name ="";}
```

para chamar ela:

```
string valor = main.name;
```